# Oracle how to do a limit?

Tags: oracle, dbi

I have to limit to **2 rows**. 
But can't do it for a SQL-Fetch.

```
select *
from employee;
```

Comment: What is the version of Oracle being used?

Comment: Why can't you use `FETCH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 select *
 from  
 ( select * 
 from emp 
 order by data desc ) 
 where ROWNUM <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the query as:

```
select *
from
  top_n_test
order by
  num
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

The select first n rows only selects the first n rows.

Comment: In the question: "But can't do it for a SQL-Fetch." ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest way is to

```
select * 
from employee
where rownum <= 2;
```

but the question is what exactly do you want to do with that.